# How to automatically install an app on your iphone?

Tags: ios, installation

I'm looking to find a way to install an app automatically on an iphone.  An example would be:

I have an app called my.app. 
It's located on my desktop on my mac.

When I plug in my iphone to my computer it automatically installs my.app on to my iphone.

Is this possible?  Any ideas of how I could possible do this or get a workaround?

Or, it needs to prompt the user to install it. The app doesn't need to automatically install; it just needs to automatically prompt the user on the iPhone to ask if they want to install it or not.

Comment: It COULD be possible but your users would require jailbroken devices. Other than that, no.

Comment: Are you talking about a jailbroken phone? I'm pretty sure Apple-approved app installations can only go through iTunes (or Xcode).

Comment: no it needs to be a regular iphone.  I'm looking to find a work around to the app store almost.  the app needs to be on an external drive the iphone and connect to.  then it automatically promps the user if they want to install or not.  also thanks for fixing tags josh haha

Comment: I think they call this behaviour a "virus"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Legally, you can't. Apple (and maybe some authorized third party) is in charge to deliver the packages using the App Store.

However, if you don't "care" about the legal part, try jailbreaking the phone.

Comment: why cant we just allow the user to install the program similarly to how one would jailbreak the iphone? Except instead of jail breaking the iphone it just install the app?  Now is something like that possible?  If there is a way to jailbreak it there has to be a way to have a user manually install an app or some program on the phone..?

Answer (score 0):

If you set up your device with apple configurator (you can find it in the Mac app store) as supervised device you can edit it's profile to include all the apps you want. If you update the profile (add, remov, update apps) the device will be updated when you plug it in while apple configurator is running.

If your intent is only to bypass the app store you could use web deployment (requires a valid ad hoc or enterprise distribution profile just like apple configurator - or a jailbroken device). See this guide: http://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-apps/#app43ad871e

Comment: Well my goal is to make an app which thousands of people will use... but i know for a fact apple wouldnt approve of it... because it would make them lose money in the long run. mainly because they are stubborn and wont fix it for us.  I need the app to be easily installed so when I sell this product people dont have to go crazy trying to set it up or else the product will get a bad rep and no one will purchase.  I need it to be as seamless as possible.  I was thinking maybe replicating the jailbreaking installation to install this to your iphone. Idk if it would be an app or just a program

Comment: Also I can't make everyone have to jailbreak their iphone because that is unappealing to many people... Do you have an example of a website that does the wireless distribution thought their website?

Comment: Well you can only install apps that are downloaded through the app store (iTunes..) or you need to have an enterprise account but that limits to in-house distribution and you must not distribute it publicly (apple will revoke your certificate, delete your account, sue you...).

Comment: If your question was "how can I bypass iOS installation checks without jailbreaking" you should have put it that way.. Distribution of approved apps (even paid apps when you are volume purchase program member) without the app store is possible after all

Comment: well i need to share it to the public... how is jailbreaking ok?  I need to do something similar to that... im pretty much trying to replicate that installation system per-say... and then distribute it.. but apple wouldn't ever approve of this in the app store..

Comment: Even if you manage to install it, it can't be launched without jailbreak/AppSync because a valid signing identity is needed and checked for at every launch

Comment: cant you just create another validating server? it might be hard but has to be possible.  I know of some people that have created "fake" validating server in order for something to login or pass thought.  Might that be possible?

Comment: if you get hold of apple's private keys for its certificates.. otherwise this is impossible